# Formatting date variables to remove unwanted characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using jQuery to help me fill some input boxes with dates. The format displayed is `MM/DD/YYYY`:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepickstart").datepicker();
});
$(function() {
    $("#datepickend").datepicker();
});
```

input boxes:

```html
Start Date: <input value="" type="text" name="datepickstart" id="datepickstart" required></input>
End Date: <input value="" type="text" name="datepickend" id="datepickend" required></input>
```

These are part of a form submission and on the following page the `request.form` info shows the dates as `7%2F17%2F2016`. Is there a way that I can break up the dates into individual parts so that I can write them separately? Like:

`<%=startmm & "-" & startdd& "-" & startyyyy%>`  and  `<%=endmm & "-" & enddd& "-" & endyyyy%>`

Comment: Now might be a great time to read [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dateFormat` and specified the format (`mm-dd-yy`):

```
$('#datepickstart').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
});

$('#datepickend').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
});
```

If you want get the part date, you can use this code:

```
var day = $("#datepickend").datepicker('getDate').getDate();    
var month = $("#datepickend").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1; 
var year = $("#datepickend").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
var fullDate = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
alert(fullDate);
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/rU5Nc/346/